# Spring Graphql Client code executing a query to receive a flux

Tags: spring, spring-boot, graphql-java, spring-graphql

Anyone know who to use the Spring graphql Client to receive a Flux of objects ? https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/docs/current/reference/html/#client.httpgraphqlclient
What expression would you code for the client to execute a query to receive a flux of objects

Trying to solve a problem and expecting an answer

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could you provide more information? What's the remote GraphQL schema like? Which query are you targeting? Can you show some code snippet?